# How to implement Proxy pattern in Objective-c (using runtime and other objc features)

Tags: objective-c, proxy-pattern

Sometimes I need to implement [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) in ObjC. I need it in cases were I create *inner* *subject* in runtime and do not want to move creation logic out from the proxy. Sometimes I use couple of objects inside the proxy, also I prefer use ARC to memory menegment. Now I implement it using C++ style:

```
- (void)setProperty:(CGFloat)value
{
    _innerObject.value = value;
}


- (CGFloat)property
{
    return _innerObject.value;
}

<...>
```

I think that it is not a best way,  I think that exist more easy way. I want to use ObjC runtime and forward messages automatically.
How I can do it without write every set/get method by hand?

Comment: Is your class a subclass of `NSProxy`?

Comment: No, my class is NSObject, but I can use NSProxy, I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`- forwardingTargetForSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardingTargetForSelector:) "[r]eturns the object to which unrecognized messages should first be directed". So:

```
// Will be queried for every message that is sent to `self` but
// which `self` does not itself implement.
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return _innerObject;
}
```

Comment: As I understand, I have to add this method to my class and remove my implementations. Am I right? How I should implement properties? May be I should use dynamic?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply: yes. There's also a `-forwardInvocation:` which would allow you to capture the full content of messages supplied to your proxy in case you want to dispatch them later rather than now, but it's a slower mechanism than `-forwardingTargetForSelector:`.